# Passing a struct array[x] with a pointer, when the pointer gets it value from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm currently trying to program a SCARA robot and i've got a question about accessing a certain array[index] of type struct with a pointer.

Re-writing in better variable names, not exact code:

```
// struct
typdef struct mystruct {
double a, b;
int c, d;}
mystruct

// prototypes
mystruct * msPtrFn(doesnt matter)
void Function2(mystruct *msPtr) 
void UseMallocInfo(mystruct *msPtr)


void main()
{
mystruct * msPtr;
msPtr = msPtrFn(doesnt matter) // function call

//msPtrFn definition
mystruct * msMallocPtr = malloc(sizeof(stuff))
msMallocPtr[0].a = 1234
msMallocPtr[0].b = 2341
msMallocPtr[0].c = 3452
msMallocPtr[0].d = 3425 .. and so on 61 more times

return msMallocPtr;

// calling function2
function2(msPtr);

//function 2 definition
ask user for irrelevant stuff
//this is where my question comes in:
//How do I pass in a specific subscript to UseMallocInfo?
// ie.
msMallocPtr[8].a
msMallocPtr[8].b
msMallocPtr[8].c
msMallocPtr[8].d
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ill answer questions as quick as possible. I am about 4 months into learning programming for what its worth.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you mean `&msMallocPtr[8]`

Comment: `&msMallocPtr[8]` which is equivalent to `&*(msMallocPtr + 8)` which can be simplified to `msMallocPtr + 8`.

Comment: Beautiful! That seems to work! Would you mind explaining what exactly that means? is it something like 'The address of the pointer to the 9th element'?

Comment: when asking a question, always post code that cleanly compiles, unless the question is about a compile time problem.